# Executing sc.exe from .NET Process unable to start and stop service

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, restart

I'm trying to restart the service from a remote machine. Here is my code. The problem is that I need to enter `startinfo.filename = "sc.exe"` since I'm putting `"start /wait sc"` this is causing an error. Here is my code, any thoughts. Also if anyone has any idea how to keep the cmd window open after this is ran so I could see the code that was ran that would be awesome.

```
string strCommandStop1;
string strCommandStop2;
string strCommandStart1;
string strCommandStart2;
string strServer = "\\" + txtServerName.Text;
string strDb1 = "SqlAgent$" + txtInsName.Text;
string strDb2 = "MSSQL$" + txtInsName.Text;

strCommandStop1 = @"start /wait sc " + strServer + " Stop " + strDb1;
strCommandStop2 = @"start /wait sc " + strServer + " Stop " + strDb2;
strCommandStart1 = @"start /wait sc " + strServer + " Start " + strDb2;
strCommandStart2 = @"start /wait sc " + strServer + " Start " + strDb1;

try
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    startInfo.Arguments = strCommandStop1;
    startInfo.Arguments = strCommandStop2;
    startInfo.Arguments = strCommandStart1;
    startInfo.Arguments = strCommandStart2;
    startInfo .FileName = "sc.exe";

    Process.Start(startInfo);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why not use SMO to do this, or at least the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class?

Comment: Also, I suggest you get into the habit of working with `e.ToString()` isntead of `e.Message`. You lose less information that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28VS.71%29.aspx) class? This way you would have much better control of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

"start" is an intrinsic command in the cmd.exe shell, so use cmd.exe as Filename;

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.Arguments = "/c start /wait sc.exe " + server + " Stop " + database;
si.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(si);
```

Also, your successive re-assignment of the Arguments property looks strange. You need to call Process.Start for each command-line you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your startInfo object is going to actually call:

```
sc.exe start /wait sc <strServer> Start <strDb1>
```

Also, is there a particular requirement you have to use sc instead of using the ServiceController class from the System.ServiceProcess library?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone I went with using the ServiceController class and that made everything so much easier. Thanks for all your help.
J

Answer (score 0):

The console can remain open if you use cmd /k and without the start which seems to open a new cmd.
so it should be something like cmd /k sc.exe " + server + " Stop " + database;